# Highcharts - Organizing the raw data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm looking at all the demos of highcharts and they all seem to follow a very simple data structure:

```
Categories,Apples,Pears,Oranges,Bananas
John,8,4,6,5
Jane,3,4,2,3
Joe,86,76,79,77
Janet,3,16,13,15
```

I have data that doesn't fit this organization very well. I could do it this way of course but it would be a pain to set up and impossible to update.

I'm looking to build stacked bar chart that shows categories (say  Group1, Group 2,  Group 3) and sales staff with their sales. The problem gets complicated as sales staff can be in more than one group at one time; and as this goes over time can return to the original category.

So Category 1 (Group 1) will be pulling data from a table like that below

```
Date  |  Date | Group |
Start |  End  | Lead  |

1990  |  1991 |  AAA  |
1991  |  1994 |  BBB  |
1994  |  1996 |  AAA  |
```

The way highcharts is designed detail (John, Jane, Joe) is associated with every Category.  Creating the chart shown above would be simple. But what about something more involved, something with 4 categories and 200+ names

```
Category Date Start Date End  TotDays Name
Apples  5/11/1994   3/1/1995    294 sc
Apples  5/19/1995   6/28/1997   771 lb
Apples  12/13/1997  5/12/1998   150 og
Apples  1/30/1999   11/1/1999   275 bs
Apples  11/1/1999   11/27/1999  26  jm
Apples  11/27/1999  4/6/2002    861 ak
Apples  4/6/2002    1/1/2003    270 hs
Apples  5/10/2003   9/13/2003   126 hv
Apples  9/13/2003   6/5/2004    266 fs
Apples  6/5/2004    9/18/2004   105 oh
Apples  9/18/2004   7/16/2005   301 bh
Apples  7/16/2005   9/29/2007   805 jt
Apples  9/29/2007   4/17/2010   931 kp
Apples  4/17/2010   6/1/2010    45  sm
Apples  7/31/2010   8/25/2012   756 dp
Apples  8/25/2012   10/20/2012  56  hn
Apples  10/20/2012  9/14/2014   694 pq
Apples  12/13/2014  2/3/2015    52  al
Bananas 4/29/1995   7/16/2005   3731    bh
Bananas 7/16/2005   10/11/2005  87  jt
Bananas 12/10/2005  7/12/2009   1310    aa
Bananas 9/19/2009   5/7/2011    595 ss
Bananas 5/7/2011    8/17/2013   833 dg
Bananas 8/17/2013   12/7/2013   112 db
Bananas 12/7/2013   2/3/2015    423 fs
Cherries 10/1/1993  8/1/1994    304 dj
Cherries 8/12/1994  12/19/1995  494 jc
Cherries 12/19/1995 6/24/1996   188 st
Cherries 6/24/1996  8/23/1997   425 wj
Cherries 8/23/1997  1/31/1998   161 jg
Cherries 1/31/1998  5/12/2001   1197    wj
Cherries 5/12/2001  9/29/2001   140 ft
Cherries 9/29/2001  7/16/2005   1386    bh
Cherries 11/17/2001 12/13/2003  756 wj
Cherries 5/1/2004   3/11/2006   679 mm
Cherries 7/16/2005  12/14/2006  516 jt
Cherries 3/11/2006  7/15/2006   126 fs
Cherries 7/15/2006  4/28/2007   287 jc
Cherries 4/28/2007  9/1/2012    1953    fs
Cherries 10/14/2010 11/2/2012   750 gg
Cherries 9/1/2012   11/2/2012   62  dg
Cherries 11/2/2012  2/3/2015    823 gg
```

At this point I don't see how to work with highchart. Can anyone point to a way to use tables such as that listed above?

SEE Fiddle of what it *should* look like:

http://jsfiddle.net/MAYO/eLam1Lo1/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has far more to do with data organization and representation in general than it does with anything highcharts specific.

You need to work out the details of how important the different aspects of the data are, and what about them you want to show, and then figure out what methods of display will do what you need.

Once you do that, then it's time to worry about how to format the data for a charting library. But you're nowhere near that point.

(and if you did find a way to put all of that into a single stacked bar chart, it would be extraordinarily useless)

Things to think about:

Are the changes over time important? Or just totals?

Are the categories really important? If so, and if the people change categories all the time, then you'll need to break the data out into chunks based on who was in each group at each time.

Do you really need the numbers at the user level?

More than likely, to make any meaningful sense out of this data is going to require multiple visualization types working together.

For example, a chart listing totals by group, and another listing individual users. Another showing the change in composition of each group over, or each individuals participation in each group over time, etc.

Maybe not the answer you're hoping for, but your question isn't really answerable as asked.

**[[ udpate:**

In the case of the example fiddle that you posted, taking your data and applying to something like that `results` in this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/up7a5nk5/

There is a lot of room for playing with options, but I have a hard time seeing that as being useful still...

Your data is basically this, one series per person, with one data point per time period in which that person is represented:

```
{
  "name":"aa",
  "data":[
    {
      "x":1,
      "low":1134190800000,
      "high":1247371200000
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I put up a fiddle of what it should look like.

Comment: wow!!. At first glance that looks perfect. I was giving up on highcharts and going to use javascript and divs.

Comment: The purpose is to view at a glance who is leading what committee; or who is the lead. In some cases there is really complex data and in other cases there is little turnover.